# Hybrid application with iphone?

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I want to create a simple game, and as I understand it OpenGL will make that happen but could I make the menu, high score list and every thing except the game with regular xcode?

For instance, for Windows Phone (where im comming from) you could create XAML/DirectX where you totally could make the menu in xaml/cs and then the game in directx

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the main view element in iOS is called an UIView and you use it to present openGL content on it. This results in being able to overlay it with any other views, subviews, put it in a superview, have multiple views with openGL content... All the events such as touches work as well. In summery implementing openGL in iOS UIView will simply override the visual content of the view leaving rest of the functionality as it is.